# How long should one study daily in order to avoid burnout?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, learning

I googled this quite a lot and it seems that I can't find the answer to the above question. I can find details on what to do to avoid the burnout but nothing specific on how long should one study new material every day.

Let's say that it is up to you to set a due date for when you are done with the learning, you have to digest around 20 books and you need to practice. How much new material and old material can you study per day without burning out?

Comment: Good question, but I do not know if there is one specific answer. It depends on many factors : personality, the type and complexity of material you study, how you study etc. One good advice, though is to distribute study time over the day/week.